# Eliminate typecasting when extracting from Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have requirement where a `Map` is of the type `HashMap<String, Object>`. Value in the Map is of the type `Object` as the values are of different data types. Though using `Object` helps solve my problem, I have to typecast every time i try to `get(key)` from the `HashMap`.

Is there any library available that would help me do away with these frequent typecasting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you imagine you could do it without casting if the types are different? Would the library you are talking about guess which type you have in mind, or would you transmit that information telepathically? The actual answer to your question is: do not put objects of different types into the same map, it is a bad practice.

Comment: @Dima You are absolutely right about it. But the number of values is not large enough to justify creating a dedicated class so at the moment i'm relying on a Map and it really hate that.

Comment: Isn't "hating it" reason enough to create a class? What's the downside?

Comment: Fair question again. I got just 5 values and i'm not sure if it would be right to create a class for them. But yes, i'm more than willing to get away from using a Map.

Comment: How does it matter how many values? `Integer` for example only has one value, and is still a class. Consider also `Void`, that does not have any values *at all*. Class is a description of the object's function and behavior, not merely a container for properties.

Comment: @Dima, why don't you write that as an answer? I find it a better answer than the existing ones, but can not currently upvote it ...

Answer (score 3):

No. If you have to store the values of your Map using `Object` type, you can't avoid casting.

You should consider if it makes sense for all the possible types of values that can be in your `Map` to implement some common interface or have a common base class. This would allow you to replace `Object` with a more specific type, and reduce (and perhaps even eliminate) the need of casting.

Answer (score 2):

You could hide the cast inside your own impl:

```
public class FlexiMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    public <T> T getType(String key) {
        return (T)get(key);
    }
}
```

Java can infer the type when you use it.

```
Boolean b = myMap.getType("foo"); // no cast
```

Comment: Ouch ... shouldn't you mention the disadvantages of this approach? Such as completely bypassing the compile time type system and possibly causing *heap pollution*?

Comment: @Bohemian That's one way to deal with it. But as Dima had pointed out in the comments i can't find a middle ground between creating a Class and storing in a Map, Or at least not worth the effort. If i'm willing to create a new class, might as well create one for the values rather than as a wrapper for the Map.